# Pearson correlation in R

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster

I have two different parameters raster data, Which are temperature (Worldclim 19 variables, masked to my study area) and habitat variables (i.e., Elevation, NDVI, Northness, Eastness,Aspect, Slope,Distance to (Rivers, Settlements,Roads),Global land cover and soil layer. 
I want to perform Pearson's correlation coefficient analysis among these parameters.

I need help in 
1) how to add these layers in R raster package.
2) How to conduct Persons and sperman correlation on these raster data sets.

Comment: Why arcgis-desktop is a tag when you are asking for r? This site is focused on one answer - one question. For the first one, google it... There are hundreds of blogs showing how to load rasters in R and stack them. For the second one, use `as.data.frame()` to raster stack and make correlations to the output data.frame

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the raster package just create a list of raster paths and then create a raster stack. Once in the stack you can run the pairs function to create pairwise plots with correlation coefficients

```
rasterPaths <- list.files(path='...folder with rasters', pattern= 'tif' , full.names=TRUE )
rasStack <- stack(rasterPaths)
pairs(rasStack,cor = TRUE )
```